# How to use VB.NET windows service to check if application is running and Close or Kill the application

Tags: vb.net, service

I have a VB.NET windows service that I created to start another VB.NET application on a virtual machine reboot.

How can I use the VB.NET windows service to check if the application is running and stop or restart the application?

Comment: What have you tried so far? Show us some code.

Answer (score 0):

[See CheckApp - by me](https://github.com/linuxman4/CheckApp) I've coded this Windows service application to check every 5000ms (5 seconds) if a specified process running. You can modify the code with your own relevant processes (e.g. starting that process again if stopped.)

You can install the service using `InstallUtil` from `Tools > Command Line > Developer Command Prompt` in order to deploy the service.

> Make sure you have logged on as Administrator on Visual Studio.

As soon as the service starts, the timer `Refresher` starts which does your required work.

Go to **Services** and find `App Checker` after installing it, then finally enable it.

[image: Main Code for Refresher activity]

Hope it will help you.